# How to assert an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable, assert

I am wondering if this approach is the best to assert an IEnumerable string value, can you guide me on how I can assert this in order to get back some content in the whole string?
Thanks.

```cs
[CodeStep("Assert message")]
public void Test()
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URLHere");
   var response = string.Empty;
   Task.Run(async () =>
   {
       response = await client.GetStringAsync("message/All");
   }).Wait();

   var messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(response);
   Assert.IsTrue(messages.ToString().Contains("TextHere"));
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ToString()` on an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: Please post code, not an image of code. Also include details like what is `Assert`. Most assertion libraries have a way to determine if a collection contains an element.

Comment: It should be either `messages?.Contains("TextHere")` to determine whether `messages` contains the value "TextHere", or `messages` should be an `IEnumerable<char>`. It's unclear whar is actually returned from the HTTP call.

Comment: An `IEnumerable<string>` is not _one_ string, but a way to get a whole bunch of strings (potentially). It's somewhat similar to a list or an array, but where those are fully realized data structures in memory, an enumerable is more like a way to get the next item and then the next and the next and so on. -- so the question is, what _do_ you really want to assert about it? That it produces _any_ item? That, you can simply do with `messages.Any()`. Or do you want to check if one item is exactly `"TextHere"`? then you can do `messages.Contains("TextHere")`.

Comment: Or maybe you want a LIKE-like search? Then you could do `messages.Any(item => item.Contains("TextHere"))`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *"assert an IEnumerable string value"*. You're missing the part where you describe *what* you're trying to assert (presumably it's that one of the strings in the IEnumerable equals your test string or that one of the strings contains the test string).

Comment: This would also potentially work: `Assert.IsTrue(string.Concat(messages).Contains("TextHere"));`

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't the best way to check that one of the messages contains the word `TextHere`. There's no requirement for the underlying sequence to render its contents as part of `ToString`, and in fact implementation like `List<>` don't.

Try using the Linq `Contains` extension method instead:

`Assert.IsTrue(messages.Contains("TextHere"));`

If you want to check if any of the string contains the substring `TextHere` then use `Any`:

`Assert.IsTrue(messages.Any(t => t.Contains("TextHere")));`

Comment: And Enumerable.SequenceEqual if you know what the entire sequence should be.